# How to read this format of JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

I have a problem to load this json in a JSONObject, i tried some combinations but it didn't work, for example i was able to load the Openweather JSON format easy but this one i got nothing on my Log as output

this is the format of Json:

```
{
    "marcadores": [
        {
            "lat": 38.632682,
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Les Urques",
            "mar": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/mar/moderado.svg",
            "viento": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/viento/viento_S2.svg",
            "simbolo": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/cielo_dia/sol.svg",
            "imagenTemp": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/pastillas_temp/temp_25_a_31.svg",
            "temperatura": 29,
            "lon": 0.032945
        },
        {
            "lat": 40.078478,
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Cala d'Orpesa la Vella",
            "mar": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/mar/debil.svg",
            "viento": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/viento/viento_SE2.svg",
            "simbolo": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/cielo_dia/nube_alta_sol.svg",
            "imagenTemp": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/pastillas_temp/temp_25_a_31.svg",
            "temperatura": 31,
            "lon": 0.134357
        },
        {
            "lat": 40.008969,
            "id": 3,
            "nombre": "El Serradal",
            "mar": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/mar/debil.svg",
            "viento": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/viento/viento_SE2.svg",
            "simbolo": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/cielo_dia/nube_alta_sol.svg",
            "imagenTemp": "appvalenciaplayas/static/images/pastillas_temp/temp_25_a_31.svg",
            "temperatura": 31,
            "lon": 0.034107
        },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please put your response as a string in JSONObject
i am showing to you how to get all fields values like this 
please read my code and apply my code as per your need.

```
try{
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(yourResponce);
    JSONArray jarray=json.getJSONArray("marcadores");

    for(int i=0;i<jarray.length;i++)
    {
        JSONObject jobj=jarray.getJSONObject(i);

        String lat=jobj.getString("lat").toString();
        String id=jobj.getString("id").toString();
        String nombre=jobj.getString("nombre").toString();
        String mar=jobj.getString("mar").toString();
        String viento=jobj.getString("viento").toString();
        String simbolo=jobj.getString("simbolo").toString();
        String imagenTemp=jobj.getString("imagenTemp").toString();
        String temperatura=jobj.getString("temperatura").toString();
        String lon=jobj.getString("lon").toString();

    }


}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your `JSON` as follows

```
    String str = "your_json_here";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("marcadores");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject elementJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = elementJsonObject.getString("id");
            // all fields to be accessed as above
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Arya R. did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you need to create a POJO with attributes `lat,id,nombre...`
2. Read JSON array elements and convert JSON to Class (You can use jackson or Gson)
3. Use your object whatever you want

In addition this code piece may help you, but auto convertion is more pretty with some libs.

> ```
> try{
>      JSONObject json=new JSONObject(yourResponce);
>      JSONArray jarray=json.getJSONArray("marcadores"); 
>  for(int i=0;i<jarray.length;i++)
>  {
>      JSONObject jobj=jarray.getJSONObject(i); 
>      String lat=jobj.getString("lat").toString();
>      String id=jobj.getString("id").toString();
>      String nombre=jobj.getString("nombre").toString();
>      String mar=jobj.getString("mar").toString();
>      String viento=jobj.getString("viento").toString();
>      String simbolo=jobj.getString("simbolo").toString();
>      String imagenTemp=jobj.getString("imagenTemp").toString();
>      String temperatura=jobj.getString("temperatura").toString();
>      String lon=jobj.getString("lon").toString(); 
>  }}catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
> ```

Some other helpful links

- https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/
- http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gson framework. You create a model class with the same Json response attributes/structure . This way you do not need to use getString( ) and getObject().
Example: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html